Guava RateLimiter doesn't allow within permit
I am using Guava (v 32.1.1) RateLimiter as following:
    int permitsPerSecond = 10;
    RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(permitsPerSecond);
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < permitsPerSecond; i++) {
        boolean tryAcquired = rateLimiter.tryAcquire();
        System.out.println("tryAcquired: " + tryAcquired);
    }
    System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + stopwatch.stop().elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
    System.out.println("No. of permit requests processed: " + i);

The output I receive is:
tryAcquired: true
tryAcquired: false
tryAcquired: false
tryAcquired: false
tryAcquired: false
Time elapsed: 2
No. of permit requests processed: 5

Since I've set permitsPerSecond to 10, shouldn't all tryAcquire() call return true?
